# Linux command to generate file on server if pinged server is down, and a different file if it's up

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, awk

Okay, slightly strange/specific question, but I have a command on linux to ping a server 3 times, and return the number of successful replies

`ping -c 3 google.com | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }'`

I want to extend this so it creates a file on the server named "server_is_up.txt (if the server is up (ie - the number is 3), or writes a file "server_is_down.txt" (if the server is down, obviously).

Tried this but it didn't work:

`ping -c 3 google.com | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ if ($1 == 0) { > host_is_down.txt } else { > host_is_up.txt } }'`

I'm sure it's obvious, but can't think where to put the "> host_is_down.txt" part.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ping -c 3 google.com | grep '0 received' && touch host_is_down.txt || touch host_is_up.txt
```

Comment: This returns host is up for everything, because "received" is returned in any ping, doesn't matter if there's a response or not: "3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2016ms"

Comment: Your answer didn't work directly, but modifying it slightly like so did the job :D Thanks - ping -c 3 google.com | grep '0 received' && touch host_is_down.txt || touch host_is_up.txt